# 2x3 between subjects experimental design - Analysis omitting one level possible?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I would very much appreciate your help in the following matter:

I have a 2x3 experimental design with the two factors product type (levels: small/large) and eco-label type (levels: design 1/ design 2/ design 3).

For the design of the data set I would like to split the data into two studies:

1) Study 1a where I perform an ANOVA with product type (levels: small/large) and eco-label type (design 1/ design 2)
2) Study 1b where I perform an ANOVA with product type (levels: small/large) and eco-label type (design 1/ design 3)

My question: is that actually possible to use reduce the data set for the ANOVAs omitting in each analysis one of the levels of one factor (in study 1a I would omit the level design 3; in study 1b I would omit the level design 2). I am really interested in comparing the eco-label design 1 with either design 2 (study 1a) or design 3 (study 1b). In terms of theory/hypotheses, I would prefer to split the description of the studies into two studies, but I am not sure whether this can be done.

Does anybody know a paper where such an approach has been taken?

Thanks a lot, any feedback is very much appreciated!

Lena